# SET VALUE of party group in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, variables, group-by, grouping

I want to set value of the **grouping** column in **myclass** table with the value of group by partying them with only 4 people.

this is the **myclass** table ORDER BY **id:**

```
id  | name | grouping |
-----------------------
 1  | abc  |          |
 2  | bca  |          |
 3  | sad  |          |
 4  | tyu  |          |
 5  | hjh  |          |
 6  | lpk  |          |
 7  | ass  |          |
 8  | drc  |          |
 9  | dfg  |          |
 10 | drt  |          |
 11 | dgf  |          |
```

this is what i want :

```
 id | name | grouping  |
------------------------
 1  | abc  |    1A     |
 2  | bca  |    1A     |
 3  | sad  |    1A     |
 4  | tyu  |    1A     |  ==> the max name of group 1 is 4 name, and then change to group 1B
 5  | hjh  |    1B     |
 6  | lpk  |    1B     |
 7  | ass  |    1B     |
 8  | drc  |    1B     |
 9  | dfg  |    1C     |
 10 | dgf  |    1C     |
 11 | drt  |    1C     |
```

i want to make it in Mysql query, but i actually want to use it in Laravel PHP. Thanks before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THIS ANSWERS THE ORIGINAL VERSION OF THE QUESTION.

You can calculate the value in a `select` by doing:

```
select t.*, (1 + (@rn := @rn + 1) div 4) as grouping
from t cross join
     (select @rn := -1) params
order by id;
```

You can set it using similar logic:

```
set @rn := -1;

update t
    set grouping = 1 + ((@rn := @rn + 1) div 4)
    order by id;
```

Comment: actually this works great, but what if i want to make the grouping to 1A, 1B, 1C not 1,2,3 ??

Comment: @www.cahyonegoro.com . . . Then you would have a different question, and you should have asked it as a new question.

Comment: Upvoting because you did answer the question.